# Why does autolayout not work anymore in xcode 7.2?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode7.2

See the photos below, am I missing a big memo about these changes or is this just more evidence of Tim Cooks lacking focus and neglect of product? What is the solution?

(notice how my table-view cell does not show up on the storyboard, I can't add auto-layout constraints and my table does not reach the bottom of the screen on simulator)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have no view selected, so there's nothing to add constraints for.

Comment: I can see the cell in the object list on the left, so probably your constraints have resulted in the cell having a zero size or appearing outside of the table bounds

Comment: Alex, it does not not matter whats selected man, nothing works:http://imgur.com/abnQQSx 


@Paul idk why that would happen and i have no ability to add constraints so cant really fix it.  

p.s remember back in the day when layouts just worked? You did not need to do anything with constraints unless you were doing something special and everything just worked and sized regardless of screen....even if you programmatically set the frame to 320 width it would know when it was on a ipad and scale properly....god I hate Tim Cook.

Comment: Personally, I find that while constraints do have quite a learning curve, they are much more flexible than the old springs and struts.   I also haven't had any issues with Xcode 7.2 in particularly. I suggest that you try re-creating your scene.  Also, I doubt that Tim Cook personally went to the Xcode team and said "hey, let's mess up auto layout OK?".  Typically stuff gets set to 0 frame or off screen because you selected "update frames" without having the appropriate constraints in place.

Comment: This is not a learning curve issue , its a "I cant even add constraints bc the software does not work or has been altered beyond intuition"  ...ive used constraints for years, id love to use them now.

and no Tim Cook did not go and say that, he caused it via his leadership, by putting all the focus on margins and profits instead of product perfection...the cracks are starting to show.

Comment: Did you accidentally deselect "use auto layout" on the storyboard?

Comment: No I did not, this much would be clear if you went off of my more detailed thread with pictures verifying this instead of just closing them because you could not figure out the problem.

Comment: You should edit this question rather than opening a second.  My question regarding "use auto layout" was asked before you opened the second question.  People are trying to help, but it seems like it may be something specific to your project or installation.  I would suggest that you open a support incident with Apple who can help you directly

Comment: Stop playing man....your abusing power period. You know that once a question goes more than a few hours with a negative score the chances of getting a good answer are slim to none....it does not matter how well I edit this q. This q should be deleted and the other one should be opened.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Select tableView, and the click on autolayout pin.
2. Set Bottom layout to 0, with pin is On.

Comment: That would be a great way to do it....IF Appple had not screwed up xcode and i could add constraints:http://imgur.com/abnQQSx

Comment: You actually have to select the view. You haven't selected anything - you may be zoomed out too much.

Comment: That would be a lie, I have a table selected inside a viewcontroller.